# c# linq query on data table to select all minimum values with duplicates

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I've a data table like:

```
ChNo     ChData
1         0.1
1         0.2
2         0.0
1         0.1
2         0.2
1         0.1
1         0.1
2         0.0
```

For minimum values based on chNO's i written query like

```
var minLPData = from minData in loadProfileData.AsEnumerable()
                                orderby minData["ChNo"]
                                group minData by minData["ChNo"] into g                                
                                select new
                                {
                                    ChNo = g.Key,
                                    ChData = g.CopyToDataTable().Compute("Min(ChData)", string.Empty)
                                };
```

But result i'm getting like

```
ChNo     ChData
1         0.0
2         0.0
```

I want all minimums based on ChNo including duplicates

```
ChNo     ChData
1         0.1
1         0.1
1         0.1
1         0.1
2         0.0
2         0.0
```

What change make me to get target table.

Comment: I think you should not group your results

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as I understand it, you need to:

1. Group your elements by channel
2. Find the minimum value for each channel
3. Find all elements that have this value

So, here we go:

```
var minLPData =
    from data in loadProfileData.AsEnumerable()
    group data by data["ChNo"] into gData
    orderby gData.Key
    let minValue = gData.Min(d => d["ChData"])
    select new
        {
            ChNo = gData.key,
            ChData = gData.Where(d => d["ChData"] == minValue).ToList()
        };
```

That will give you an enumrable of anyonymous type. You can then transform it to a dictionary. The ChData member in the anonymous type is a list of the same type than the initial data, but you can do a Select if you want to transform it.

The main difference here comparing to your code is the use of the Where() clause in the construction of the ChData member (and the use of the let clause to calculate the min).

Edit: if you want the list of values on one level (instead of a list of lists), you can use SelectMany:

```
var plainList = minLPData.SelectMany(g => g.ChData.Select(d => new { ChNo = g.key, ChData = d["ChData"] }));
```

Comment: Great! its working Thank you so much Evren. And if i change gData.Min to Max can i get all maximums?

Answer (score 1):

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> lowestChNoRows = loadProfileData.AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy(r => r.Field<double>("ChNo"))
            .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
            .First();
```

If you want a new `DataTable` with the lowest value rows:

```
DataTable tblLowestChNoRows = lowestChNoRows.CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: it showing specified cast is not valid, and i already changed double to int but still it showing like that

Answer (score 1):

Why are you grouping? It seems to me you just want the minimum values of all your list.

```
var list = loadProfileData.AsEnumerable().ToList();

// Get the minimum value
var minValue = list.Min(v => v["ChData"]);

// Get all elements that have the same value than the minimum value
// Order them by ChNo
var minimums = list.Where(v => v["ChData"] == minValue).OrderBy(v => v["ChNo"]);
```

Then you can transform this list as you want, like:

```
var minLPData = minimums.Select(v => new { ChNo = v["ChNo"], ChData = v["ChData"] });
```

Comment: I need miminum values based on channels 1,2... of all minimums not only one as i explained my post

Comment: how can we convert data table to tolist directly? it showing me error cannot convert datatable to list

Comment: @nag: I added AsEnumerable before ToList(). It really depends of your types, I don't really know what types you have in and out so I'm just guessing, then you can adapt. And this code does return all the minimumS, not just one. Added some comments for clarity.

Comment: @EvrenKuzucuoglu Yup! its working great! for max values i changed to list.Max but i'm getting none results? still any change is to made?

Comment: I don't see why you would have a difference with Max. You should be able to find at least one element.

Comment: But what if channel 1 having 0 minimum and channel2 having 0.2 minimum?

Comment: @EvrenKuzucuoglu see i've channels 1,2... and having data for each channel then i need to get minimum and maximum for all channels including duplicates of it if minimum value repeated for respective channel

Comment: Then my answer is wrong... Unmark the answer and change your question so as to reflect these details. It was not clear in the first place- I'll create a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Prepare the data
var table = new DataTable();    

// The type must be specified explicitly,
// otherwise it will be string
table.Columns.Add("ChNo", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("ChData", typeof(double));

new[]
{
    new {Key = 1, Data = 0.0},
    new {Key = 1, Data = 0.1},
    new {Key = 2, Data = 0.0},
    new {Key = 1, Data = 0.0},
    new {Key = 2, Data = 0.1},
    new {Key = 1, Data = 0.0},
    new {Key = 1, Data = 0.0},
    new {Key = 2, Data = 0.0},
}
.ToList().ForEach(p => table.Rows.Add(p.Key, p.Data));

// Make a projection, so it is easier to work with
var data = table.AsEnumerable().Select(p => 
    new { Key = p["ChNo"], Data = p["ChData"] }).ToArray();

var minValues = data.GroupBy(p => p.Key)
    .ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Min(i => i.Data));

var res = data.Where(p => minValues[p.Key] == p.Data)
    .OrderBy(p => p.Key)
    .ToArray();
```

[image: Result]